# How to detect blackberry useragent and do a redirect

Tags: php, blackberry, jwplayer

I'm using video player (jwplayer) and it seems not working fine on blackberry
and looks like blackberry doesn't support either flash or html5.

So I would like to redirect any blackberry visitors:

```
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Then will use:

```
if(preg_match('#########',substr($useragent,0,4))){
echo "Yes blackberry";
}else{
echo "No blackberry";
}
```

Will this idea works ? And if yes, then what should I put instead of ######### to recognize blackberry?

Thanks.

Comment: There are [quite a few questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=blackberry+user+agent) regarding this.

Comment: @jprofitt i did made search before post but the exact question was with one reply was based on paid services :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569652/blackberry-detection-then-redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php

$ua = strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
$pos_blackberry = strrpos( $ua, 'blackberry' );

$pos_webkit = strrpos( $ua, 'webkit' );
$url = "http://m.yoursite.com/";

if ( !($pos_blackberry === false) ) {

  if ( !($pos_webkit === false) ) {
    // redirect
     header( 'Location: ' . $url );
     die;
  }
}

?>
```